# What pronoun do Catholics typically use to refer to the Eucharist?

Tags: catholicism, communion, transubstantiation

Catholics believe that the communion bread and wine are not bread and wine anymore but the Lord Jesus Christ himself appearing as bread and wine.

Since in Catholic dogma the communion bread and wine becomes Jesus Christ, who is himself a person, that raises the question about what pronoun is used to describe the Eucharist. This change of substance (Transubstantiation) does not include the change in form, though.

**What pronoun do Catholics typically use to refer to the Eucharist? Do they use the pronoun "He"?**

Comment: To clarify, the Eucharistic elements become *the body and blood* of Jesus. We do not refer to sombody's blood as 'he', nor to any part of their body.

Comment: @DJClayworth I'm having docternal issues with that.  He, That is Christ the second person in the Trinity, becomes the Eucharist,  does he not?  I hope you are putting together an answer with sources that suggesting differently.  What part of "He" is missing when we recieve him?

Comment: I have to disagree with DJClayworth. "The whole Christ is truly present, body, blood, soul, and divinity, under the appearances of bread and wine..." (USCCB.org) So yes, the Eucharist is a "he," just as God is a "he."

Comment: I have further edited - I hope it is a better/more neutrally worded now, while retaining the original intent.

Comment: @ThaddeusB As currently phrased it seems to me to mean, or at least be interpretable as, "Does there exist at least one Catholic who uses *he* to refer to the Eucharist?" I don't think that's what's intended.

Comment: @MattGutting  Added "typically" - does that help?

Comment: Please tell me first as to what gender is attributed to the Holy Spirit.Let us not forget that we are trying to measure God and His wisdom in terms of human yardsticks. Language, for one, is a purely human form of communication with all its shortcomings.

Comment: *What pronoun do Catholics typically use to refer to the Eucharist? Do they use the pronoun "He"?* assumes Catholics use a pronoun to refer to refer to the Eucharist. They don't, they call it the Holy Eucharist, Holy Communion, the Blessed Sacrament, etc.

Comment: @FMS: Every noun can be substituted with a pronoun. So there must be a pronoun that can be used to refer to the Eucharist. Is it "it" or "he"? If the Eucharist is the Lord Jesus Christ, and the Lord Jesus Christ is a "he," then the Eucharist must be a "he."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never heard [of] a pronoun used for the Eucharist.

This section [**II. WHAT IS THIS SACRAMENT CALLED?**](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ccc_css/archive/catechism/p2s2c1a3.htm#1327) in the *Catechism of the Catholic Church* lists the different names given to the Eucharist:

1) *Eucharist*, because it is an action of thanksgiving to God.

2) The Lord's Supper.

3) *The Breaking of Bread*.

4) The *memorial* of the Lord's Passion and Resurrection.

5) The *Holy Sacrifice*.

6) *Most Blessed Sacrament*.

7) *Holy Communion*.

8) *The holy things (ta hagia; sancta)*.

9) *The bread of angels, bread from heaven, medicine of immortality, viaticum ...*

---

### Expressions

He (the LORD) is truly present in the Blessed Sacrament of the Altar

or

He is truly present under the appearances of bread and wine

Cf. Eucharist Hymn: [*Adoro Te Devote*](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/liturgicalyear/activities/view.cfm?id=1083) by St. Thomas Aquinas (1225-1274):

> Hidden God, devoutly I adore Thee,
>   **Truly present underneath these veils**:
>   All my heart subdues itself before Thee,
>   Since it all before Thee faints and fails.
>
> [...]

Comment: The pronouns in this answer refer to the Lord, not to the wafers or wine specifically. I think it's right that pronouns are not used for the sacrament itself. "I'm just going to put him in the tabernacle" is facetious; "I'm just going to put it (or *this*) in the tabernacle" might deny the supernatural nature of a sacrament. "I'm just going to put the Sacrament in the tabernacle" would be far more common.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I've recently started using the term "He/Him" for the consecrated hosts and the wine. I know a few others who do so, but it's far from general. I adore Jesus when I adore the Sacrament; I talk to Him and He's there in the Sacrament. If Jesus is indeed truly and completely present in the species, then it seems not inappropriate to use the pronoun - just rare.

Comment: @AndrewLeach In agreement.

Comment: We do not use the pronoun HE when referring to the Holy Spirit; do we ?  Let us not forget that English in only one of those thousands of languages which the faithful use.  There could be languages which are capable of expression  without resorting to the use of pronouns.  For instance, the construction of a verb in Sanskrit language of India is such that it is indicative of the subject, its gender and number and also the tense .  So, the very question as to whether a pronoun should be used  to denote the Holy Eucharist,  should, in my opinion, be laid to rest.